# How to run a C++ binary built with bazel but without bazel run?

Tags: c++, bazel

I have built my Bazel based application using `bazel build` command. Now I want to copy generated binary to another directory/computer and run it using `./binary_name` command.

Error message I got is saying that: `error while loading shared libraries [...] cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` which is what I expected.

How can I set the path for the missing shared libraries to successful run the binary? Or is there any other way to run a binary without need to call `bazel run` command at all?

Comment: You need to put the shared libraries where the executable can find them. Keywords to explore: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `-Wl,-rpath=`.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows, Unix does not launch executables (including shared objects) from your current working directory (which is why you need to run `./my-program`. The system dynamic loader search certain directories for the `.so` files. These often include `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`

You can add to this list using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or by specifying this using the `-Wl,rpath=` linker directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the entire `bazel-bin/foo/bar/binary.runfiles` directory and then run `binary.runfiles/my_workspace/foo/bar/binary` it should work. Note that you need to dereference the symlinks, not just copy them (`cp -L` or `rsync -L`).

If you're still having trouble, please edit your question to include the output of `ldd ./binary_name`, which will detail which shared libraries are being found (and where), and which aren't.

Bazel links some dependencies as shared objects, depending on the `--compilation_mode`, the toolchain, and attributes on some rules (like `linkstatic` and `linkshared`). The details of how those interact are complicated. When Bazel links things as shared objects, it embeds relative paths to all of the shared objects it creates into the binary.